# How to filter out this?

Tags: list, filter

Im a beginner..

I have searched now for some hours for a solution without success.

I have following list with 3 columns and 3 items

1. Date     Id     Place
2. 190725   1        A
3. 190724   1        B
4. 190725   2        B

I want to make a view and filter out the newest entries for each id and then show only the items with Place = B

Meaning this would be the result

190725   2       B

Is there any easy solution for this?

Edit: 
This was only an example, i have many items in the list. What I want to do is to filter so i get the newest unique id for every id, and then filter out everything except place B

Comment: If the solution below meets your requirement, please remember to mark it as the "answer" with the green check :) welcome to the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be possible to achieve via OOTB view and filter, you would need to do customization,

Create a custom page, add content editor webpart to add html and javascript.

Use JSOM or REST API to get data from SharePoint.

Filter the data using json.filter functions based on you requirement, this would be where you would filter unwanted data and keep only relevant data.

Create html based on json data(ideal would be to create jquery datatable so that you get filter, sorting functionality)

ref link to create jquery datatable - http://sp77.blogspot.com/2016/12/display-sharepoint-list-data-in-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks! Will try it

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** There are some assumptions with this solution (assuming you only have your 3 items as your question states), but try this.

- **Create a view**
- **Filter:** Show Items only when the following is true : Place is equal to B
- **Sort:** Modified (Show Items in Descending Order)
- **Item Limit:** Number of Items to Display: 1

**NOTE:**
There may need to be additional work or thought, if you have A B C D E F G and you want the newest entry for each Place limited to 1 item per "Place".

Comment: Hello, no sorry maybe i didnt explain myself clear enough. This was only an example, i have many items in the list. What I want to do is to filter so i get the newest unique id for every id, and then filter out everything except place B